# iOS Static Library into Static Library symbol not defined

Tags: iphone, ios

i have to create a iOS static Library that include an other static library. So i create a new Static Library project whit XCode 4 and then I include and use a 3rd part static library.

When i try to test my static library there is "symbol not found" for all method of 3dr part static library...

So to be more specific i write a static libA.a that use static libB.a and in new test project i include only libA.a and all method of libB.a that are missing symbols. Even i include also libB.a in test project there are missing symbols...

There is a way to create a static library that is a wrapper of another static library???

Can someone tell me all the build setting that i do in xcode?

Thanks.

Comment: What prevents you from linking the App against all needed static libraries?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the statement "and all method of libB.a that are missing simbol" please?  What do you mean?

Comment: ok, in my test project of library the buil fails with this error:  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7...  and follow by a list of all methods of 3td part library...

Comment: Nobody prevents to add in my app all static library nedeed for libA.a but in my target test project i want include only my static library, beacause for 3dr part static library there is a license restriction for distribuition but not for use...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the .a of the 3rd party static library. You do however need to include the header files of the 3rd party static library if you intend to reference them in your own static library.

Comment: You will have to link against both libraries though and it's during linking that you get the "symbol not found" error.

Comment: In my static library project i include all header files necessary and it's build ok. By in test project i use only libA.a header files... right? The test project use only libA.a and libA.a use libB.a

Comment: You can just include headers for libA.a if you do not use anything from libB.a in your test project. However, when you compile the final project make sure you include libB.a as well as libA.a, otherwise you will get linker errors.